# If the universe seed is for creating universes, why does Hearts think he can destroy the Zenos with it?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-manga, dragon-ball-heroes

In Dragon Ball Heroes episode 9 of the anime , Hearts says that with the universe see he will destroy the Zenos. But the universe seed supposedly is for creating universes. Why did he say so? How would he use the universe seed to destroy the Zenos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Universe seed could also be considered as an energy source of sorts and we see hearts supposedly generate these boxes which can trap people or objects in from which energy is absorbed by the Universe Seed until nothing remains as you can see [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eRgo6EgAmW0), from the 6:00 mark.

He threatens to do the same to the Universe 6 fighters, Trunks and Vegeta until Kamin and Oren stop them.

I believe the Universe Seed here acts as a massive energy source which can perhaps be used to destroy Zeno or resist their power.

For instance, a similar comparison could be made to an experiment performed by Fu in Xenoverse 2. While the character would distort time and create alternate scenarios to simply absorb energy for experimental purposes(Note: He doesn't get stronger by absorbing the energy). He is able to pass this energy on to the Future Warrior, who with his help, is capable of pushing SSJB Goku into turning Ultra Instinct and is also capable of holding his own against Ultra Instinct Goku.